# How to use {withTheme} in styled component.? any one give real-time example please

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Actually, I don't understand how to use {withTheme} in styled component and its usage also. So anyone gives proper code with using {withTheme} in styled component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`withTheme` is helping you to reach theme variables from your component props. When you define a theme you can normally use them in styled components but if you define your component with `withTheme` HOC you can use those variables in your component.

```
// Define our button, with the use of props.theme
const Button = styled.button`
  color: ${props => props.theme.fg};
  border: 2px solid ${props => props.theme.fg};
  background: ${props => props.theme.bg};
`;

// Define our button, but with the use of component.props
const ThemeButton = (props) => (
  <button style={{background: props.theme.bg, color: props.theme.fg, border: `1px solid ${props.theme.fg}`}}>
  {`this button is using: ${props.theme.fg} and ${props.theme.bg}`}
  </button>
)

const ButtonWithTheme = withTheme(ThemeButton);

// Define our `fg` and `bg` on the theme
const theme = {
  fg: "palevioletred",
  bg: "white"
};

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <div>
    <Button>Default Theme</Button>
    <ButtonWithTheme></ButtonWithTheme>
  </div>
</ThemeProvider>
```

You can check in here https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-sky-kgjqj?fontsize=14

Comment: Thanks @hurricane now i understood, it's worked well.!